# Parsing enums to Class

Tags: c#, enums

The array `AllUnits` is a list of lists. And i am trying to add new object in to the second list. I've got also an Enumeration called `EMilitaryUnits`, and i have a classes with the same names as the strings in the Enumeration. And i don't know how to transform an Enumeration to Class i have tried like this

```
_City.Owner.Military.AllUnits[(int)_UnitType].Add(new Object.GetType(_UnitType.ToString()));
```

And the error is

> Error 1 `object.GetType()` is a 'method' but is used like a `type`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code `new Object.GetType(_UnitType.ToString())`?

Comment: op is thinking GetType will return the input string's type what I understood

Comment: It appears that OP has regular classes whose names correspond to the `EMilitaryUnits` enum value declaration names, and seeks a way to create an instance of the class corresponding to the enum name of value of `_UnitType`.

Comment: exactly what alex has said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this part:

```
new Object.GetType(_UnitType.ToString())
```

Try this (substiture  with the namespace where your types are defined):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("<namespace>." + _UnitType.ToString()))
```

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'ConquerCA.Classes.Utility.Units.BaseUnit"

Comment: Ah, right, you may need a cast as well. Try adding cast to (BaseUnit)? That is, (BaseUnit) Activator.Createinstance(....)

Answer (score 1):

Given that:

> OP has regular classes whose names correspond to the `EMilitaryUnits`
>   enum value declaration names, and seeks a way to create an instance of
>   the class corresponding to the enum name of value of `_UnitType`.

My recommendation would be to build a static factory to do this, as the types will be fixed and the enumeration as well. The below is an example illustrating how this could be approached.

```
public enum EMilitaryUnits
{
    Cavalry,
    CanonFodder,
    // ... others
};

public interface IMilitaryUnit 
{
    // rest
}

public class Cavalry : IMilitaryUnit 
{
    public Cavalry() {}
    // ... rest
}

public class CannonFodder : IMilitaryUnit 
{
    public CannonFodder() {}
    // ... rest
}

public static MilitaryUnitFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<EMilitaryUnits, Func<IMilitaryUnit>> map = 
        new Dictionary<EMilitaryUnits, Func<IMilitaryUnit>> {
            { EMilitaryUnits.Cavalry, () => new Cavalry() },
            { EMilitaryUnits.CanonFodder, () => new CanonFodder() },
            // more for the others
        };

    public static IMilitaryUnit Create(EMilitaryUnits kind)
    {
        return map[kind]();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
_City.Owner.Military.AllUnits[(int)_UnitType].Add(MilitaryUnitFactory.Create(_UnitType));
```